# Are there any differences between all the cues (besides cosmetic)?

Tags: pure-pool

In Pure Pool, you can unlock different cues as you progress levels.   My question is that are there any differences between them (besides cosmetic)?  Does my accuracy or any other stat increase by using a higher level cue?

Answer (score 1):

Just cosmetic. Pure pool doesn't have any accuracy or power stats or anything like that. It's all handled by how you handle the analogue stick.
If you are after more power then put some front spin on the ball, careful though, it might make the cue ball climb the cushions.